# Issue with building ASP.NET 5 library

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, c#-6.0

That's strange. I can't build my project (one library). I don't see any errors from IntelliSense. But when I try to build via F5 it shows be loads of errors. I can't understand why, since I have all references installed.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the 'Project' column of the error list you'll see that it is only DNX Core 5 that is failing to build. Not all libraries support DNX Core yet. Try removing it from your project.json file.

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { } <-- remove this line
},
```

Comment: In my project.json file I have no external libs, only MS related - http://screencast.com/t/lQI4dprBu

Comment: @Vnuuk it's not a reference but one fo the platform targets. I've updated my answer to reflect that.